# Build an android application to open firefox

Tags: android, firefox

I want to build an android application which can open  and close "android Firefox" For opening i have done by following code

Question :- how to close this opened firefox from my android application.

---

```
String url = "http://google.com/";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
     this.startActivity(intent);
```

---

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot close another app from inside your app. That would be a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but the ActivityManager class has a killBackgroundProcesses method which could solve your problem! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html